# Trying to increment counter in table

Tags: tables, environments, counters

I have a table in which I'm trying to increase the first column by 10 on every addition of a step. I've seen a few articles that show to use a token to do this but I just can't seem to get it right.  When I do the following it just prints the final "step" number:

```
\newcounter{procstep}

\newtoks\@procitems
\newcommand\addprocitems[1]{\@procitems\expandafter{\the\@procitems#1}}
\newcommand*\resetprocitems{\@procitems{}}
\newcommand*\printprocitems{\the\@procitems}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{
    \addprocitems{\theprocstep & #1 & \\}
    \addtocounter{procstep}{10}
}

\NewEnviron{procedure}{
    \setcounter{procstep}{10}
    \vspace{0.1in}
    \par
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Instructions} & \textbf{Check} \\
        \endhead
    \BODY
        \printprocitems
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}
```

For Example if I did

```
\begin{procedure}
    \step{Hello}
    \step{How are you}
\end{procedure}
```

I would get

```
30 Hello
30 How are you
```

Rather than

```
10 Hello
20 How are you
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your example is incomplete and the question is unclear

Comment: Maybe you should introduce a new counter at every step and give it the value of your main counter. Then it should do it the right way.

Comment: Updated question with example.  @TeXnician - Not sure what you mean example?

Comment: @RossW: Your posted code is incomplete and incompilable, it misses the relevant packages and `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is an example where one has to construct the tabular content with `tokens`

I suggest to use a new columntype at `N` with the `array` package which does the addition and the `\step` command displays the step then.

In principle, the `\theprocstep` could be used within the `N` type, but it would print the number in header as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{procstep}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\addtocounter{procstep}{10}}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{%
  \theprocstep & #1 & \\%
}

\makeatother

\NewEnviron{procedure}{%
    \setcounter{procstep}{0}%
    \vspace{0.1in}
    \par
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|N{1cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
      \hline
      \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Instructions} & \textbf{Check} \\
      \endhead
      \BODY
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
  \step{foo} 
  \step{foobar}
  \step{more foobar}
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - Works perfectly....It's going to nag me though as to how you can expand the \theprocstep before putting it into a token :)

Comment: @RossW: I'll to provide a token - version, but not today or tomorrow. Remind me in case I should forget ;-) Happy Texing!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the way you devised, but you have to fully expand `\theprocstep` before adding to the token list register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ltablex,environ}

\newcounter{procstep}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@procitems
\newcommand\addprocitems[1]{\@procitems\expandafter{\the\@procitems#1}}
\newcommand*\resetprocitems{\@procitems{}}
\newcommand*\printprocitems{\the\@procitems}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{procstep}{10}%
  \edef\temp{\theprocstep}%
  \expandafter\addprocitems\expandafter{\temp & #1 & \\}%
}

\NewEnviron{procedure}{%
  \par
  \vspace{0.1in}%
  \setcounter{procstep}{0}% reset the counter
  \BODY % build the table body
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Instructions} & \textbf{Check} \\
  \endhead
  \printprocitems % deliver the table body
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
  \step{Hello}
  \step{How are you}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, I add a different version with `xparse` and `expl3`.

Since the table body is built before typesetting the table, there's no need to use global variables. I added also an optional argument to `\step`, just in case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ltablex,environ,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_rossw_procedure_step_int
\tl_new:N \l_rossw_procedure_body_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\step}{O{10}m}
 {
  \int_add:Nn \l_rossw_procedure_step_int { #1 }
  \rossw_procedure_add_step:fn
   { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_rossw_procedure_step_int } }
   { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \rossw_procedure_add_step:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rossw_procedure_body_tl { #1 & #2 & \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \rossw_procedure_add_step:nn { f }

\NewEnviron{procedure}
 {
  \par
  \vspace{0.1in}
  \BODY % build the table body
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1cm}|X|p{1.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Instructions} & \textbf{Check} \\
  \endhead
  \tl_use:N \l_rossw_procedure_body_tl % deliver the table body
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
  \step{Hello}
  \step{How are you}
  \step[5]{Half}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```

[image]